# How to use WAN ip address to host site?

Tags: networking, dns, port-forwarding, wan, web-hosting

I'm was trying to do Port Forwarding to host website from home server in my TP-Link TL-WR841N Router. I use static IP address of my server, I opened port "80" from Windows Firewall. I even changed DDNS(Dynamic DNS) software. But I Could't host site. After hours of router and Windows troubleshooting i found problem. "The Public IP and WAN IP are different".

If i type WAN IP in Browser then i can access my site but if i type public IP, it's not able to access site and so as DDSN software( cause they use public IP addresses.). Following are my IPs.

**Public IP: 113.153.246.38**

**WAN IP: 101.75.30.156 (From TP Link Router)**

**DDNS Software: DuckDNS(which uses my public ip, not WAN ip)**

How to do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: I've tried it. Still not Working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like a Fibre to the Cabinet (FTTC) broadband connection I'd expect this.

The problem should be easy enough to fix. From a browser on the LAN, search for "whatsmyip". The resulting address is the public address you need to use when accessing the server from the Internet. Ignore anything else.

You also need the LAN address of course and this is what you configure in your router's NAT configuration.

Comment: You are right about public IP. But in my case, my website is being hosted from my WAN IP not from my Public IP. That's the problem.When I type my WAN IP in browser i can open website. And that WAN IP is also not Static IP, it keeps on changing after few hours like my public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also had the exact same problem and finally found that i am having two ips for WAN and PUBLIC ip. The browsers see the Public IP but when I ping this PUBLIC IP , there is no ping response.

WHen I ping the WAN IP I get the ping response .

So If you set up your port forwarding , make sure that you **DONT use PUBLIC IP** .

Always **USE WAN IP** for connecting to your whatever servers you have setup in your LAN.

Also as a side note , I am also using a TP-link router . After you setup port forwarding , make sure that in the security tab , you enable **REMOTE MANAGEMENT**.

Without this option enabled , router rejects all incoming packets .